# Initializing jQuery selectize entry on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, selectize.js

I am using [selectize](https://selectize.dev/) for a report to allow specific search terms to be added filter criteria. I save off the input entries to local storage (via [Lockr](https://github.com/tsironis/lockr)) so that when users return to the page their criteria is still populated.

However, I am not sure how to load the selection from `onInitialize`.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    !function (l) {
        "use strict";
        function e() { }
        e.prototype.initSelectize = function () {
            l("#selectize-skus").selectize({
                plugins: ["remove_button"],
                persist: !1,
                createOnBlur: !0,
                create: !0,
                onChange: function (value) {
                    Lockr.set('skus', value);
                },
                onInitialize: function () {
                    var skus = Lockr.get('skus');
                    if (skus)
                    {
                        this.setValue(skus);
                    }
                }
            });
        },  e.prototype.init = function () {
         this.initSelectize() },
        l.BillListSelectize = new e, l.BillListSelectize.Constructor = e
    }(window.jQuery), function () {
         "use strict";
         window.jQuery.BillListSelectize.init();
     }();
    </script>
```

You can see that when `onChange` fires, I save the selections to storage. Then `onInitialize` should pull those values back from storage and assign, if they exist. However, this doesn't seem to be working and I'm not sure why. I've seen others reference `setValue` but typically out of the context of the initializer.